# How to print return value of function

Tags: powershell

So i have this simple `function` that return my current script location:

```
function Get-CurrentDir
{
    $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
}
```

And i want to print this, so i try from PowerShell ISE after the function declaration:

```
Write-Host $(Get-CurrentDir)
Write-Host (Get-CurrentDir)
Write-Host Get-CurrentDir
```

And this is my output:

```
Write-Host $(Get-CurrentDir) --> Write-Host $(Get-CurrentDir)
Write-Host (Get-CurrentDir) --> Write-Host (Get-CurrentDir)
Write-Host Get-CurrentDir --> Write-Host Get-CurrentDir
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, you would need to get the variable from the script scope, like so:

```
function Get-CurrentDir
{
    $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
}
```

also this won't work interactively. you would want to read more [about_scopes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) in PowerShell.

Comment: This is not return anything

Comment: What does this $script doing ?

Comment: its calling the variable from the script scope, i've updated my answer with a link to explain scopes in powershell